# moodle quiz not completing when criteria is met

Tags: php, moodle

Good morning,

I have a course with 12 quizzes that I would like to require the participants to take in sequential order.  At the end of each video is a "video code" the user has to provide as an answer to the quiz.  I have done the following:

- toggled completion criteria to true under Administration > Edit settings
- checked require grade for Activity Completion under Current Course > QUIZ # >   Edit settings (Administration navigation)
- gave the quiz a mark of five, an answer,  and the grade @ 100% under Administration > Quiz admin > Question Bank > Questions
- set the grade to pass to 5.00 via Administration > course admin > grades > click the cog under the necessary quiz (must be on grader report and edit turned on)

Now, what I cannot figure out is why my grade in the gradebook is not green, which if I have this correct should mean the grade is passing. Currently, I am not able to move to the second quiz even though my grade is passing and my test user has completed the activity.

Comment: How is the quiz graded when the student provides the video code? Do you do a manual grade override? And what version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: The video code is captured via the quiz question, and the pass is handled by the 4th point made above.  I do not do a manual override to pass the quiz.  This is Moodle 2.6.

Comment: You might be better asking this at the moodle forums. It can all be achieved via the front-end.

Comment: yep, I believe my forum post there predates this one.  Basically I changed the criteria from **pass** to a grade of 100%. That solved my issue, [moodle forum post](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=327132#p1315315)